# Kotlin type erasure error in corda state migration

Tags: java, kotlin, migration, corda

I have a Corda State **CarA** having field **drivers**: Set<**CustomDriverClass**>. But in next version, I want to change the datatype of Set<**CustomDriverClass**> with Set<**String**>. But corda doesn't allow to change it directly
(Reference: https://corda.net/blog/a-developers-primer-on-cordapp-upgrades/).

So, I added a new field name => **driversV2**: Set<**String**> & removed the **drivers** field. Then added a depreciatedDeserialisationConstructor(1) for this new field added.

Now problem is,
"**Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature**" occured.

**Reason for the Issue**: It’s because the JVM signature of depreciation constructor and main state class are taking as same. The only difference between them is the datatype difference inside Set.

```
Set<CustomDriverClass> & Set<String>
```

which is not considered due to Type Erasure in Kotlin.

**Quick fix**: I found a fix by simply changing the position of driversV2 in main class & hereby changed the JVM signature there.

But please let me know how to properly handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably begin with remove the drivers field. Technically, you should not delete a field in a contract state. You won't be able to load any existing states on the ledger after you delete a field from a old version state.

You need to add new field as nullable and preserve old fields. Once all nodes on the network have upgraded, you can stop populating the old field, but you should never stop having and understanding the old field, because anything old loaded from the ledger will populate it and complain if it isn't there.

As for the constructor cannot tell the difference between Set and Set, you are on the right path of fixing it.

Comment: But isn't the deserialization constructor ( with old version input parameters & returning new version parameters) added is for that purpose? meaning to load existing states with drivers (old field) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your state

```
data class ExampleState(
        val custom: Set<CustomDriverClass>
        override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf()
) : ContractState
```

Change to

```
data class ExampleState(
        val custom: Set<String>
        override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf()
) : ContractState {
    @DeprecatedConstructorForDeserialization(1)
    constructor(
        val custom: Set<CustomDriverClass>,
        participants: List<Party>): this(emptySet<String>(), participants)
}
```

Instead of `emptySet()` on the last line, you can convert from `Set<CustomDriverClass>` to `Set<String>` if possible so that the deserialization of old states to the new set contains the old data, or if not possible, just ignore it and init the set as `emptySet<String>`

Comment: Hi Amol, thanks for the answer. But I think this wont work. the same name cannot be used for another datatype. I got deserialization error, have you tried this? only it solved when I change the name (means like adding a new field) with required data type and then did the same in deserialisation constructor.